# Sort an array of objects that is the second child of an array - By object date time

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I sort an [array of objects by date] that is the second child of an array ?

I get the following array structure:

```
array = [
    ["2022/04/14", [object]],
    ["2022/04/15", [object]],
    ["2022/04/20", [object, object, object]],
    ["2022/04/25", [object, object]],
    ["2022/04/30", [object]]
];

//where each object contain a date property that include time
//for exemple each object get :
{
param1:"someText"
date: Fri Apr 15 2022 18:00:00 GMT+0200
paramX:"someText"
}
```

For the days that include more than one object, objects are not sorted by time.

I've texted the following method, but can't get success with it

```
const sortedArray = array.sort((a, b) => {
      return new Date(a[1][1].date).getTime() - new Date(b[1][1].date).getTime();
    });
```

How can I sort object by time for each day of this array ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely there is a more elegant way to solve this problem but here is my approach.

```
// Here is the result of sorting the objects
const formattedArray = [];

const sortedArray = array.forEach((item, index) => {
  const sortedObjects = item[1].sort((a, b) => {
    return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
  });

  formattedArray[index] = [item[0], sortedObjects];
})
```

You don't need to use `.getTime()`.

Comment: thank you ! I can't say if it's elegant or not, but I can say that it works and does the job.